# Adding Multiple Attachments in PHPMailer

Tags: php, attachment, email-attachments, mailer

I am trying to attach multiple images in the attachments. I have used forearch for every attachment but, its not getting the tempname and name when I use foreach, I'm probably doing something wrong. Below is the code and errors:

**Input HTML**

`<input id="upload-file" class="upload-file" type="file" name="upload-file[]">`

**var_dump of $_FILES['upload-file']:**

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(47) "WRANGLER_AW13_GIRLONTOP_A4_LANDSCAPE_300dpi.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php41DC.tmp" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(91742) } }
```

var_dump for name and temp_name:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\hmg\process-email.php on line 66

Notice: Undefined index: tmp_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\hmg\process-email.php on line 67

NULL 
NULL
```

**CODE:**

```
foreach($_FILES['upload-file'] as $file) {         

    $name = $file['name'];
    $path = $file['tmp_name'];
    var_dump($name);
    var_dump($path);

    //And attach it using attachment method of PHPmailer.

    $mail->addattachment($path,$name);
}
```

Comment: Be warned that none of the submitted answers handle uploads safely, as per [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php). Base your code on [the file upload examples provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/), which handle files correctly.

Comment: My PHP is realy rusty in the meantime, but how is [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps#L20) anymore safe? It just creates a temp file, which we already have? Even if there is some improvement I do not see, I would call it error handling, but not *safe*. Speaking about security, we need to make sure, the temp files can not be executed, because of server missconfiguration, preventing a spam relay (captcha or something like that), etc... @Synchro

Comment: It’s safer because it guarantees that the temp file was created by PHP and was not injected from some other source. Look at the docs for `move_uploaded_file` for more info; there’s a whole chapter in the PHP docs about this.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to the evil side of PHP. The `$_FILES` is not that, what a developer would expect.

```
//wrong code
$img1 = $_FILES['upload-file'][0]['tmp_name'];
$img2 = $_FILES['upload-file'][1]['tmp_name'];

//working code
$img1 = $_FILES['upload-file']['tmp_name'][0];
$img2 = $_FILES['upload-file']['tmp_name'][1];
```

So you need something like

```
$totalFiles = count($_FILES['upload-file']['tmp_name']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalFiles; $i++) {
   $name = $_FILES['upload-file']['name'][$i];
   $path = $_FILES['upload-file']['tmp_name'][$i];
   $mail->addattachment($path,$name);
}
```

Here is [some example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps) from the PHPMailer repository.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for all the answers. I am sure all of your approaches would work just fine, but I decided to solve it myself. This code solved the problem

```
$validAttachments = array();

foreach($_FILES['upload-file']['name'] as $index => $fileName) {
    $filePath = $_FILES['upload-file']['tmp_name'][$index];
    $validAttachments[] = array($filePath, $fileName);              
}

foreach($validAttachments as $attachment) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($attachment[0], $attachment[1]);
}
```

I hope anyone who has the same problem gets some help from here ...

Answer (score 1):

Most of the solutions here are based on forms.

So i came up with a simple solution if you want to attach all files from a particular directory.

```
$file_to_attach_directory = 'files/';
if ($handle = opendir($file_to_attach_directory)) {
    try {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            $attachment_location = $file_to_attach_directory. $entry;
            $mail->addAttachment($attachment_location);
        }
        closedir($handle);
        // Send Mail
        if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo "Message sent!";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = '0';
foreach($_FILES['upload-file'] as $file) {
$name = $file['name'][$i];
$path = $file['tmp_name'][$i];
var_dump($name);
var_dump($path);
$mail->addattachment($path,$name);
$i++;
}
```